# jQuery and the :before CSS tag

Tags: jquery, css

I have a drop down box I am using to change CSS using jQuery

I have set up a series of CSS classes to use.

Two of my CSS classes also contain a :before class

Using jQuery, if I select one of the items in the box that use the :before option, there is no problem.

When I select the other CSS that uses the :before option, it is ignoring the :before part of the CSS when its displaying it.

If I choose the CSS with the :before, then choose one that doesnt use the :before, then switch to the other one, it is fine, it's just when I am switching from one CSS with :before to another CSS with :before

the jQuery I am using for changing the CSS looks like this:

```
  $("#colour").change(function () {
      var str = "";
      $("select.col option:selected").each(function () {
            str = $(this).val();
          });

          var currClass = $('#heading').attr('class');

          $('#heading').addClass(str);
          $('#heading').removeClass(currClass);

    })
```

Am I doing something wrong that is causing it not to load the :before after each selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `each()` logic looks wrong, only a single value, of `select.col`'s options, is being used.

Change the code to:

```
$("#colour").change (function () {
    $('#heading').removeClass ();   //-- Clears all classes

    $("select.col option:selected").each ( function () {
        var str = $(this).val();
        $('#heading').addClass (str); // Add desired classes back, one at a time.
    } );
} );
```

Other than that, we need to the the relevant CSS and HTML, to help with any additional problems -- like that IE-only behavior that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var currClass = $('#heading').attr('class');

          $('#heading').addClass(str);
          $('#heading').removeClass(currClass);
```

By

```
  $('#heading').removeClass().addClass(str);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunatly, that did not help.

However I have discovered a bit more information about this issue. It is only affect IE8 (on firefox and chrome it is fine).

I have not checked it on IE9 as yet, but it seems to be IE related issue